# list and dataframe combined into a json

Tags: r, json

I need to obtain a JSON like this example from R:

```
{
  "content": [
       {
           "id": "id_1",
           "classes": {
               "animal": "cat",
               "place": "house",
               "score": 75
           }
       },
       {
           "id": "id_2",
           "classes": {
               "animal": "dog",
               "place": "house",
               "score": 81
           }
       },
       {
           "id": "id_3",
           "classes": {
               "animal": "duck",
               "place": "garden",
               "score": 63
          }
       }
    ],
    "book":{
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "animalsCount": 23,
        "reference": "BH"
     }
}
```

I'm doing the following in R:

```
library(jsonlite)

df <- data.frame(id = c("id_1", "id_2", "id_3"), animal = c("cat", "dog", "duck"), 
            place = c("house", "house", "house"), score=c(75, 81, 63))

pagenum <- 1
ref <- "BH"


getJSON <- function(dfinfo, pag, ref_name){

   classes <- data.frame(animal = dfinfo$animal)
   classes$place <- dfinfo$place
   classes$score <- dfinfo$score

   df1 <- data.frame(id = dfinfo$id)
   df1$classes <- classes

   df2 <- data.frame(pageNumber = pagenum)
   df2$animalsCount <- nrow(df)
   df2$reference <- ref

   info_to_json <- list(content = classes, book = df2)
   info_to_json <- toJSON(info_to_json, pretty=TRUE)

   return(info_to_json)
}


getJSON(df, pagenum, ref)
```

But, while the "content" part shows up correctly (as a list), the "book" part appears like a list:

```
 "book":[
    {
        "pageNumber": 1,
        "animalsCount": 23,
        "reference": "BH"
    }
  ]
```

which I understand because `info_to_json` is a list, but I need it to be without [ ] as shown above, but I don't know how to achieve it, how to combine both dataframes to get a list-dataframe in the JSON.

I've tried, instead of converting the list `info_to_json` to a JSON using the `toJSON()` function, adding the following line on top of my function `getJSON()`:

```
 #'@serializer unboxed JSON
```

But this unboxes "book" if book is just a parameter (like "book"=3) but not if it's a dataframe as I have.

How can I achieve that?

And also, is there any better way to convert the dataframes into the JSON without having to specify every parameter manually? or this is the only way with R?

Comment: Regarding your last question, you can do `classes <- dfinfo[,c("animal","place","score")]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. you create a data.frame for book, but what you need is a flat list
2. the content part should be converted into a nested structure.

My solution to take care of both is:

```r
library(tidyverse)

getJSON <- function(dfinfo, pag, ref_name){
    nested_df <- dfinfo %>% rowwise() %>%
        do(id = .$id,
           classes = .[2:4])
    data_book <- list(pageNumber = pagenum, animalsCount = nrow(df), 
                      reference = ref)

    info_to_json <- list(content = nested_df, book = data_book)
    info_to_json <- toJSON(info_to_json, pretty=TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)

    return(info_to_json)
}

getJSON(df, pagenum, ref)
```

In the `rowwise()` section of the function, each row of df_info is converted to a nested df.

Comment: Thanks! it worked perfectly on the actual case I'm working on too. And also thanks for the 'nested structure' tip, I'll also implemented. It looks much better!

Answer (score 1):

Use a list instead of a dataframe, and set the option `auto_unbox = TRUE` :

```
  df2 <- list(
    pageNumber = pagenum,
    animalsCount = nrow(df),
    reference = ref_name
  )

  info_to_json <- list(content = classes, book = df2)
  info_to_json <- toJSON(info_to_json, pretty=TRUE, auto_unbox = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! yes, the list with the auto_unbox parameter did the trick.